# How to capture a button click event from a different page in a different View and make DOM manipulation in the source page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html construct in the source Page View:

```
<i id="asterisk" class="fa fa-asterisk show asterisk" ></i>
<a id="tos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#divTermsAndConditions" href="@Url.Action("TermsOfServiceFromRegistration", "Account", new { lk = ViewBag.LicenseKey })" target="_blank">
   <div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="divTAndC" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" aria-describedby="termsandconditions" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">
            @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && fetchTOSAction) {
             { Html.RenderAction("TermsOfServiceFromRegistration", "Account", new { lk = ViewBag.LicenseKey }); }
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the new View which it opens, has a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnClose" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

As you can see, it is a bootstrap button and on clicking of it, it closes the current window:"TermsofService.cshtml".
Now, my requirement is like this:
1.Capture this button click event
2.And on that event make some DOM manipulation in the source View, like :

```
 $("#asterisk").removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
```

Is it possible?
Any help will be highly appretiated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself!Bingo!
Here it is:

```
$("#divTAndC").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
    $("#check").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
  });
```

Basically, in the source view itself,bind the function on modal close.
Thats it!